# From web server, how I can get the exact GPS location of an iPhone?

Tags: gps, location, core-location

I want to run my code on web server which will track an iPhone's physical location (using mobile number of card inside iPhone).

How can I do that? Is `coreLocation` the API that gives that facility?

Answer (score 0):

Your app will have to use CoreLocation to push requests to your web server with the location. The web server cannot pull the location. I do not think you can access the phone number, but you can get the Device ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the phone's location in the browser using javascript, please see the answer at question [10567617](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057617/find-current-location-by-using-html-in-iphone) .

If you have the location in the browser, you could send it to your server with ajax or any traditional technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, through a regular web request across HTTP, you can't -- that information isn't transmitted for good reasons.   However, if you were to create an App that connected to your server's app, then yes, you could simply send the update as a packet to the server as you then have unlimited access to your phones details.