# Accessing iPhone location from a website

Tags: iphone, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geolocation API on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone)
>   [Find current location by using html in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057617/find-current-location-by-using-html-in-iphone)

Is there a way to access a users gps location information (iPhone) when they visit your website (assuming they give you permission, have location services on etc).
TIA!

Comment: Even better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Check out W3's [Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).