# Is it possible to disable google maps from requesting user location?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps, location

I'm guessing not, but I'm creating an app that gets the users coordinates using CLLocationManager, then passes the coordinates into Google maps to display directions. When the webpage opens to display, it requests the users location, and if the user says yes, it somehow affects some variables in my code. I was curious if the prompt from Google maps can be disabled, or if the coordinates that Google maps does take in can be retrieved by my app somewhere. I'm pretty sure neither are possible, just tossing it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer. NO.

The location fetching in google maps app is done through JavaScript api
more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057617/find-current-location-by-using-html-in-iphone)

if you can disable the javascript the map routing itself might not work so NO.

the part about retrieving variables, I think you can check the webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest and check the url, maybe that has some information you can fetch out.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs it, here is an answer

```
let mapView = GMSMapView()
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = false
```

Comment: Hey @Yevhenii and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Thanks for trying to answer this question here. Please do keep in mind that this question was asked a long time ago - back then there was no Google Maps app available for iOS yet, and hence they were asking how you can prevent that functionality on the web.